# VBA check entire range has valid date and is not blank?

Tags: excel, vba

```
I have a workbook like so:

Dates
01/02/2017
01/03/2017
BLANK
01/02/2017
```

I am trying to run a macro but only if all cells in my range are valid dates and not empty.

I am using the below:

```
Dim cell As Range

    'With my workbook, lets check the data
    With wb.Worksheets(1)
    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    'Data Check: Are all dates valid?
    For Each cell In Range("E9:E" & Lastrow)
    If IsDate(cell.Value) And Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
    Continue
    Else
    Exit Sub

    End If
    Next
    End With
```

But this is not working. The macro still runs no matter what! If it matters my cells in this column Are data validation lists.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for the suggestion but didn't work

Comment: Do you want to run a macro for each cell in the range if it contains a date or you just want to run a macro once only when all the cells are dates and not blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the logic a bit:

```
    Dim cell As Range

    'With my workbook, lets check the data
    With wb.Worksheets(1)
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

        'Data Check: Are all dates valid?
        For Each cell In Range("E9:E" & Lastrow)
            If Not IsDate(cell.Value) Or Trim(cell.Value) = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        ' the rest of your code.
        ' it will not get here if there are any blanks in or non dates in the range.

    End With
```

Comment: What I think is checking IsDate(cell.Value) is enough as if the cell is empty or contains some white space, IsDate can handle that cell as well.

Comment: @sktneer you are probably correct.  but I will allow the OP to test either way.